# VBA, SUM and COUNTIF Formula in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to add to my macro this formula :

```
=SUM(D2:N2)+((COUNTIF(D2:N2,"GOLD")+COUNTIF(D2:N2,"PLATIN"))*1)+((COUNTIF(D2:N2,"PLPLUS")+COUNTIF(D2:N2,"AMBASS"))*2).
```

**Code**

```
Sheets("Water").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(SUMPRODUCT(IF(OR(RC[1]=R[-1]C[1],RC[3]=""GOLD"",RC[3]=""PLATIN""),""1"","")))"""
```

but it does not work.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim nr_rows As Long

with Sheets("Water")
nr_rows = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

   for i = 2 to nr_rows
       cells(i,1).Formula = "=SUM(D2:N2)+((COUNTIF(D2:N2,""GOLD"")+COUNTIF(D2:N2,""PLATIN""))*1)+((COUNTIF(D2:N2,""PLPLUS"")+COUNTIF(D2:N2,""AMBASS""))*2)"
   next i

end with
```

Comment: It is good but at the end I would like to put the Total.. do you have a solution with your formula.. See below what I would like to do...

Comment: After `next i` you can put: `Cells(nr_rows + 1, 1).Formula = "=sum(A2:A" & nr_rows & ")"`

Comment: it does not work, there is no Value in Column A. I want the result appearing in column A

Comment: What doesn't work? In previous comment you said it's good but you want more a sum at the end of the column A. Give me an exemple